# sed with next line (`+N` option) and frequency (`~N`) together

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I am trying to retrieve 2 lines of text with sed, every 10 lines (10, 11, 20, 21, 30, 31, ...).

For lines 10 and 11 I could use `sed -n '10,11p' file` or `sed -n '10,+1p' file`. And for the range (lines 10, 20, 30, ...) `sed -n '10,~10p' file`. But is it possible to combine somehow both things?

`sed -n '10,~10,+1p' file` is not working.

I assume this is a duplicate, but I can't find any reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `ADDR1,ADDR2` with `FIRST~STEP` as `ADDR1` and `+OFFSET` as `ADDR2`, so:

```
$ seq 30 | sed '10~10,+1!d'
10
11
20
21
30
```

In anycase, note that both `~` and `+` are non-standard GNU extensions.

See `info sed 'line selection'` and `info sed 'range of lines'` on a GNU system for details.

POSIXly, you'd use:

```
seq 30 | sed -n '1n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;p;n;p'
```

Comment: beautiful! thanks. I just understood how I misused ~

Answer (score 7):

How about an  `awk` solution?

```
awk '(FNR>1) && (FNR%10<2)' file
```

- `FNR` is `awk`s automatically updated per-file line-counter
- Any condition outside of a "rule block" (`{ ... }`) that evaluates to "true" (and be it the string `1`) will instruct `awk` to print the current line, including all modifications made so far.
- So, `(FNR>1) && (FNR%10<2)` will print the current line, if it is not the first line, and if the line number is an integer multiple of 10 (or +1 from such a multiple at most). This is equivalent to "every 10th and line and the following".

Comment: I assumed awk was an option, but I am not able to learn it. I end up wasting so much time every time. Thanks!

Comment: @manolius I know, `awk` has quite a learning curve. For me it turned out worthwile, but it depends a lot on what your tasks look like.

Comment: @manolius I have added some in-depth explanation; perhaps it can serve as starting point for learning `awk` ... ;)

Comment: You could also make use of `getline` ex. `awk '!(FNR%10){print; if(getline > 0) print}'` - which perhaps makes the intent clearer

Comment: @steeldriver Nice suggestion, but for users not acquainted should probably step back from `getline`.

Answer (score 3):

Using awk we can do as shewn. NR is line number in awk parlance.

```
$ awk 'NR ~ /.[10]$/'  file
```

With `sed` we could do as shown below where we increment the hold space till we hit the 10 count of newlines.

```
$ sed -nE 'x
  /\n{9}/{
    z;x;$d
    N;p;D
  }
  s/$/\n/;h
' file
```

```
$ perl -ne '$.%10||print($_.<>)' file
```